# How can I call a web api in c# using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

So I am trying to call a api in my C# method and am not getting the response that I would be getting, if I called the api using postman or insomia.

```
public static async  Task GetObject()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            //var t = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://ipapi.co/json/");

            var y = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://ipapi.co/json/");


            var o = await y.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var j = y.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
```

The api is getting my request but its not returning the right result. You should be getting this result. Click on this https://ipapi.co/json/

What am getting is this

```
{  
   "error":true,
   "reason":"RateLimited",
   "message":"Sign up for IP Address Location API @ https://ipapi.co"
}
```

But I don't get it, when am using postman

Comment: And what response are you actually getting?

Comment: Maybe it's because you are reading the response twice? Either read as json or convert the string to json

Comment: Sidenote: your method name and variables are not very clear at representing their meaning. The method `GetObject` doesn't actually return any data, and if it did, "Object" doesn't tell you what sort of data it is. `y`, `o`, and `j` don't convey any information about the data they hold.

Comment: @Amy I updated the question

Comment: @gunr2171 I am first seeing if I can get any type of result that is correct, than I would parse the json into an object.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is ultimately a support question to the team running the API service. Rate limits are set by the developers and only the company running it can tell you what the limits are and how to work with them, even if it's as easy as adding a user agent.

Comment: @gunr2171 The limit is 1,000 requests per day, I have done like 10. It's not the developers fault, it's how am implementing it. I am not sure what am doing wrong.

Comment: You are hitting a rate limit imposed by the server. It says so right in your output. No one on Stack Overflow can tell you why that is the case. Go talk to the API creator and consult their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the user-agent header.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1");
```

Comment: Can you explain how this fixed it?

Comment: They are apparently rate-limiting non-browser requests.  You would have to ask them.

Comment: Some APIs don't allow requests without this header. If you want more detailed explanation you need the ask the developers. When something works in the browser (or postman) but not with code this is the first thing I try.

Comment: Thanks @Amy too, won't let me thank both of you in one comment

Answer (score 0):

Better to Use xNet.dll or Leaf.xNet.dll libraries
Or restsharp one
Google them 
I'm also new If ur interesting to contact me
Discord Cyx.#4260